# Implementing 3D Secure Using Datacash for Mobile Device

Tags: mobile, 3d-secure

When implementing 3D Secure on Datacash there is an option to pass in "device cagetory" to specify "whether the site is being accessed via a web browser, or a mobile phone browser"

http://www.datacash.com/gettingproducts.php?id=3D-Secure-MPI-Service#enrolment

I can't find any mention in the docs about what you would need to pass in as the value in order to specify a mobile device.

0 is for a standard web browser on a computer

I called the Data Cash support and they agreed that it is possible to use a mobile device but could not tell me how. I am waiting for somebody from there to get back to me - anybody got any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got hold of somebody in support in Data Cash who told me that this field is basically ignored by their system. Nice...

Answer (score 0):

The mobile browser option was for old, WAP browsers. If you're using a modern mobile device (tablets, etc.) then use the normal flag.